# Does construction of infinite product measure require axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am learning about infinite (countable) product measure, which the exact statement of the theorem I write below. I was wondering if the theorem requires axiom of choice or not. I would appreciate any assistance! Thank you very much!

Let  $\{X_j\}$  be a sequence of spaces and write
$$
X = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} X_j.
$$
Let $M_j$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X_j$.
A measurable rectangle with respect to the sequence $\{ M_j \}$
is defined to be a subset $W$ of $X$ which is representable in the
form
$$
W = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} W_j,
$$
where $W_j \in M_j$ and $W_j = X_j$
except for at most finite set of numbers $j$.

Then we have the following theorem:
Let $\{ (X_j, M_j, P_j) \}_{j \geq 1} $ be a sequence of measure spaces,
and write
$$
X = \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} X_j.
$$
Let $M$ be the minimal $\sigma$-algebra, of subsets of $X$,
containing every measurable rectangle with respect to the
sequence $\{ M_j \}$.
Then there exists a unique measure $P$ on $M$ with the property
that, for every non-empty measurable rectangle $W$,
$$
P(W) = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} P_j(W_j),
$$
where the $W_j$ are defined by $W = \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} W_j$,
$W_j \in M_j \ (j \geq 0)  $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This theorem implies the axiom of countable choice (and is probably equivalent to it, since I doubt its proof uses any more than countable choice).  To show this, suppose $(Y_j)$ is a countable sequence of nonempty sets, and suppose the product $\prod Y_j$ is empty.  Let $x$ be some point that is not in any $Y_j$ and let $X_j=Y_j\cup \{x\}$.  Let $M_j=\{X_j,Y_j,\{x\},\emptyset\}$ and define a measure $P_j$ on $M_j$ by $P_j(Y_j)=1$, $P_j(\{x\})=0$.  Suppose a measure $P$ exists on the product $X=\prod X_j$ as you specify.  Then $X$ is a nonempty measurable rectangle, so $P(X)=\prod P(X_j)=1$.  For each $j$, let $A_j\subset X$ be the set of points whose $j$th coordinate is $x$.  Then $A_j$ is a nonempty measurable rectangle, and $P(A_j)=0$ since $P_j(\{x\})=0$.  But in fact $\bigcup A_j=X$, since $X\setminus\bigcup A_j$ is exactly $\prod Y_j=\emptyset$.  Thus $1=P(X)\leq \sum P(A_j)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Kinda like the proof of choice from Tychonoff; and like [this lil' thing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299022/box-topology-and-axiom-of-choice/1299027#1299027). I like it!

Comment: By the way, the "adding an extra point" thing is only necessary because the statement of the theorem only says $P(W)=\prod P(W_j)$ if $W$ is a _nonempty_ measurable rectangle.  The inclusion of the word "nonempty" there is kind of silly, and if you drop it you can get a shorter version of this argument by just letting $X_j=Y_j$.

Comment: There is always a trade-off. Either allow spaces to be empty and include the word "non-empty" everywhere; or simply disallow empty spaces, and then you always have to add that extra point.

Comment: But in this case you _don't_ have to include the word "nonempty" anywhere.  The theorem is just as valid (assuming choice) if you leave it out.

Comment: Yes, because with choice the only way a product of sets is empty is if one of them is empty. The problem is that sometimes having an empty product is detrimental to your cause (e.g. if none of the multiplicands were empty), which is why without choice you need to be slightly more careful.

Comment: I suppose, but if you lack choice then probably you need to know more than just that the particular product you're looking at is nonempty.  Indeed, my answer here is a great example of that--just requiring that $\prod W_j$ is nonempty doesn't keep the theorem from requiring the full strength of countable choice.

Comment: No. But when you work without choice you need to be more careful in any case, since it can enter through the back door without you even noticing. As witnessed by history time and time again.

Answer (score 3):

Well... how do you know that $X$ is non-empty to begin with?

If $X$ is non-empty, then the definition of a measurable rectangle does not require the axiom of choice, since only finitely many arbitrary choices are made. And the definition of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra does not use the axiom of choice either. But it could be larger than you'd expect. And that might cause some issues with defining $P$.

For example if $X$ ends up as a countable union of countable sets, that $\sigma$-algebra might be $\mathcal P(X)$. And in that case, either the measure is atomic, or trivial. And it might be that neither case "fits" the case of $P$.

More concretely, $2^\Bbb N$ is consistently a countable union of countable sets. This means that if $\mu$ is any measure on $2^\Bbb N$, then it is either atomic, or $0$ everywhere. Now consider for each $\{0,1\}$ a probability measure given by a fair coin. The product measure on $2^\Bbb N$ should be neither atomic nor $0$.

Comment: Sorry about deleting and undeleting and various edits. The summer heat can do that sometimes. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was confused about the following. If each  $X_i = \{0, 1\}$, then can we say that $(0,0,...) \in X = \prod X_i$ from which it follows that $X$ is non-empty (hence no need for axiom of choice) here? or am I using the axiom already? Thank you!

Comment: My answer is not saying that if $X$ is non-empty, then the axiom of choice is not used. The first concern is that $X$ could be empty; the second concern is that you might not be able to extend the measure of the squares "correctly", as the example with $2^\Bbb N$ shows.

Comment: I see. Ok, thank you. Is the conclusion then that the axiom of choice is necessary here?

Comment: Yes. Eric showed in his answer that if you assume that you can do this sort of infinite product construction, then you can *prove* countable choice holds.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have accepted Eric's answer.

Comment: You are right :) I guess I found the comments to be helpful but just in terms of answers Eric's was more helpful. By the way I have never seen that since $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a countable union of countable sets, "this means if μ is any measure on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, then it is either atomic, or 0 everywhere." Do you happen to know a reference by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's easy. If it gives every singleton $0$, then every countable set is $0$, but then the real numbers/$2^\Bbb N$/$[0,1]$ is the countable union of pairwise disjoint sets of measure zero therefore it has measure zero as well.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was wondering, is $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ a countable union of countable sets? I thought maybe this wasn't the case because this is the cardinality of reals. or am I missing something?

Comment: In general, it is not usually the case. However, it is *consistent* that the axiom of choice fails (pretty badly, of course) and $2^\Bbb N$ is a countable union of countable sets. This was proved by Feferman and Levy in 1964.